# ¿Como puedo redireccionar a otra pagina usando TestCafe luego de hacer logueo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando redireccionar a otra página luego de un login con testCafe, pero luego del login se queda esa otra página en blanco, es decir, nunca carga, o en otras ocasiones simplemente cierra la sesión sin ingresar. El caso es que no me deja pasar a la pagina principal luego de hacer login. Yo uso conexión con VPN. ¿Saben que puede ser, algún problema de token de inicio de sesión o de VPN? ¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { Role } from 'testcafe'

const role = Role('login_page', async t => {
    await t
      .wait(10000)

      .click(Selector('button.btn.btn-dark.btn-lg.btn-block'))
      .typeText('input[name="loginfmt"]', 'my_user')
      .pressKey('enter')
      .typeText('input[name="Password"]', 'my_password')
      .click('span[id="submitButton"]')
      .click('input[id="idSIButton9"]')

}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture `My Fixture`;

test('My test', async t => {
    await t
        .navigateTo('home_page_after_login')
        .useRole(role);
});
```